# TabLayout get stuck with viewpager when screen orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I am using the design support library. I've a Fragment and inside this fragment I have another fragment which has view pager with 3 new fragment

My fragment code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment Java code

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return v;
    }

    public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Tab1();
                case 1:
                    return new Tab2();
                case 2:
                    return new Tab3();

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Tab 1";
                case 1:
                    return "Tab 2";
                case 2:
                    return "Tab 3";

                default:
                    return "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Now its all working fine but when I rotate the screen, swipe on viewpager does not work correctly. I mean it get stuck in between two tabs. Also the tab indicator also get stuck between tabs. It takes almost 6-7 swipe to go from 1st to 3rd tab. Also when swiping after rotating there is only one tab fragment which was previously choose before rotating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreateView() method, try changing this:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

to this:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
```

I had the same symptoms as you did, until I made this change.